# Can I use glm in R rms package for classification problems?

Tags: r, glm

I am using `glm` in R `rms` package. Not sure if it is the right thing to use as my `y` is a binary variable.

```
model <- glm(x ~ y, family = binomial, data = df)
```

I get a resulting set of coefficients but I am not sure if using glm for categorical variable modelling is fine.

Also, please tell me what is the dofferent between glm and gls. Thank you!

Comment: 1-) this question is off-topic, as it is a statistics, not programming question. 2-) If both the independent (y)  and the dependant (x) variables are binary, you may be better off with simpler tests, such as a chi squared or fisher's exact test to test for association